# Bioinformatic tools to map mutations to pathways

Tags: path, mapping, mutation

I would like to ask if there is any free access bioinformatic tool that can map mutations to pathways. For the mutation, I have the the change in amino acid level on the gene. I appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks in advance!